# Playing sound files in python

Tags: python, audio, mp3

What is a good package for playing MP3 files in python? It would need to be something that is maintained and is cross platform (Win, Mac, Linux) and something with a simple and repeatable call structure, rather than having to perform complex setup every time the same file is opened (I use the sounds in various loops and need to not have to constantly worry about if a channel is full or other factors). It also needs to be relatively small; I don't want to import an entire GUI toolkit just so I can play a small bell and alert sounds. Lastly, it needs to be non-blocking; I need it to play the file once and move on without locking up the entire program.

I had been using PyAudiere in order to play MP3 files from python, as it used to meet all these criteria. Unfortunately, the package has been abandoned, and so I need to find a replacement (PyAudiere was updated to python 2.6 and still works in 2.7 if you hack it by manually changing the version check, but this is not a long term solution, especially since finding a copy of the package is now difficult).

Comment: I've continued to look around and it seems like everything that supports MP3s except PyGame has been abandoned. That can't possibly be true.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Try the following libraries:

1. [PyMedia](http://pymedia.org/)
2. [pygame](http://www.pygame.org/news.html)
3. [PyAudio](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/)
4. [pyglet](http://www.pyglet.org)

Comment: PyMedia was last updated in 2006, which is even earlier than PyAudiere. PyGame I already knew about, but it is a HUGE library covering everything from rendering to controls to sounds and is serious overkill for just wanting to put alert pings into a program (i am literally just playing different noises to let people know that various things are done). I will use it if I have to but I was hoping for something a bit less heavy.

Comment: Hmm.. The only other choice is pyglet ... and like you said its really bad that there is no proper lighweight library for the same !

Comment: Pyglet runs as a subprocess that blocks the program. Pygame does as well. PyAudio reads in a complex chunkwise manner that is prone to trouble, and does not work reliably on MP3 anyway. See http://guzalexander.com/2012/08/17/playing-a-sound-with-python.html for examples.